# MapView with Overlay has performance issues

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a MapView that will contain alot of overlays. For this i've extended the Overlay class as i've heard it has better performance than ItemizedOverlay (that was calling populate for every element).
When the map is moved or zoomed, in the MapActivity, I select only the visible drawables and I call:

```
protected void RefreshOverlay() {
    Log.e("||||||||||||||||||||||||||", "RefrashOverlay()");
    mapOverlays.clear();
    mapOverlays.add(new OverlayElements(zonesP,getApplicationContext()));
```

}

The class OverlayElements extends Overlay and here i do all the drawings:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    int i;
    int sz=zonesP.size();
    int style;
    ZoneProperties zone;  

    //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    pp = new Point();
    int zoomLevelC=mapview.getZoomLevel();  
    Projection pr = mapview.getProjection();
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {   
        zone=zonesP.get(i); 
        if(zone.visible==true)
        {
            pr.toPixels(zone.point, pp);  
            xp = pp.x;
            yp = pp.y;
            if(zone.zoneSizePx<500)
            {
                //----------
                Log.e("zone radious>>",zone.zoneSizePx+"<<");                                                   
                int alfa;


                style=(int)i%2;
                Log.e("style>>",i+">>"+r[i]+" "+g[i]+" "+b[i]);
                paint.setColor(Color.rgb(r[style],g[style],b[style]));                          
                alfa=(18-zoomLevelC)*35;
                if(alfa>255) 
                    alfa = 200;
                else
                    if(alfa<0) alfa = 20;   
                paint.setAlpha(alfa);


                canvas.drawCircle(xp, yp, zone.zoneSizePx, paint);


            }
            if(zone.select!=0)
            if(zone.vState==2)
                canvas.drawBitmap(getDrawRes(zone.select,zone.eSizePx),xp,yp,null);
        }
        //----------------         
    }
}
```

Well, yeah this drawing isn't that fast :) . 
Should i go back ItemizedOverlay, and if so how can i make the populate call only once? Any optimization idea? Thank you!! :)

Comment: First, you do not call `populate()` on an `ItemizedOverlay` until *all* of the items are ready, not for each item. Second, use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent, so you know better how to optimize your code.

Comment: Well, yeah, when i have similar drawables on the Map, i call only once populate() but mostly i have different ones. I've already used the profiler and most of the time I have (on the map move or zoom): BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset, GC, DrawBitmap, GC. Thank you for the tips! :)

Comment: "when i have similar drawables on the Map, i call only once populate() but mostly i have different one" -- that does not matter.

Comment: i see, that would be what i was searching for. But i really don't know how to do it because when i create a new ItemizedOverlay, in the constructor i call first super(boundCenter(Marker)); and the   addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) has nothing to do with new drawables. How could i add a new drawable without creating a new ItemizedOverlay? Maybe you would like to have an answer.

Comment: "How could i add a new drawable without creating a new ItemizedOverlay?" -- override `getMarker()` in a custom subclass of `OverlayItem`. Here is a sample project demonstrating this, where the drawable is toggled between different images at runtime: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk

Comment: I understand, I will try to implement it tomorrow, now i'm leaving work, and I will get back to you and maybe give you the answer. Thank you! Have nice day! :)

Comment: Hei, feel free to copy your last comment to an answer so I can close the question. It works wonderful. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call `populate()` on an `ItemizedOverlay` until all of the items are ready, not for each item.

> when i have similar drawables on the Map, i call only once populate() but mostly i have different one

That does not matter.

> How could i add a new drawable without creating a new ItemizedOverlay?

Override `getMarker()` in a custom subclass of `OverlayItem`. [Here is a sample project demonstrating this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/ILuvNooYawk), where the drawable is toggled between different images at runtime.